# Unable to run the test using cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

I have installed: ruby, watir-webdriver, rspec, cucumber.

I made the folder called "features". There is cucumber test "process.feature" inside it where is one feature with 1 simple scenario. There is also folder called "step_definitions" inside "features" where is ruby file process.rb.
I try to run the test writing "cucumber process.feature" into the command line, but it says that steps are undefined: 1 scenario (1 undefined), 3 steps (3 undefined).

Could you please tell me what I am missing?

process.feature:

```
Feature:
‘User Login.’

Scenario:
Given I am logged in
When I open the process page
Then I see the details page
```

process.rb

```
Given /^I am logged in$/ do
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'http://star.teepub:000/star-web/'

code = '48702'
password = 'test'

b.text_field(:id => 'j_username').set code
b.text_field(:id => 'j_password').set password
b.link(:id => 'loginBtn').click
end

When /^I open the process page$/ do
pending

end

Then /^I see the details page$/ do
pending
end
```

Comment: Step from your .feature file is not defined, post the content of process.feature and step_definitions/process.rb files

Comment: @mechanicalfish it is added to the description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure looks like:

```
--/features
    process.feature
    ---/step_definitions
         process.rb
```

To run this feature type in command line:

```
cucumber process.feature -r step_definitions
```

Notice, that to run this command you have to be in feature directory.
After command

```
cucumber
```

you must type path to *.feature file, for example

```
cucumber features/process.feature
```

or

```
cucumber my_project/features/process.feature
```

Also you can use tags, for example

```
@some_name
Feature:
‘User Login.’

Scenario:
Given I am logged in
When I open the process page
Then I see the details page
```

Use command

```
cucumber --tag @some_name
```

In this case features, which are tagged with @same_name, will be executed.
If you place tag before Scenario and type command

```
cucumber --tag @some_name
```

again, only scenario tagged with @some_name will be executed.